# Checkout Not Working in Django, Even With Test Card Details

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

I've been following along with a tutorial for my project and I've created a checkout page, with the relevant views, models etc being created as well.

The issue I'm currently having is that my website won't accept the test card details I'm putting in and it keeps throwing the error "We were unable to take a payment with that card!". I also see the below in the console:

[image]

Below are the test card details I'm using.

[image]

Below is the checkout view that is being used. The error message I'm getting is the error message shown in the second from bottom 'else' statement.

```
def checkout(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        order_form = OrderForm(request.POST)
        payment_form = MakePaymentForm(request.POST)

        if order_form.is_valid() and payment_form.is_valid():
            order = order_form.save(commit=False)
            order.date = timezone.now()
            order.save()

            cart = request.session.get('cart', {})
            total = 0
            for id, quantity in cart.items():
                product = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=id)
                total += quantity * product.price
                order_line_item = OrderLineItem(
                    order = order, 
                    product = product, 
                    quantity = quantity
                    )
                order_line_item.save()

            try:
                customer = stripe.Charge.create(
                    amount = int(total * 100),
                    currency = "GBP",
                    description = request.user.email,
                    card = payment_form.cleaned_data['stripe_id'],
                )
            except stripe.error.CardError:
                messages.error(request, "Your card was declined!")

            if customer.paid:
                messages.error(request, "You have successfully paid")
                request.session['cart'] = {}
                return redirect(reverse('products'))
            else:
                messages.error(request, "Unable to take payment")
        else:
            print(payment_form.errors)
            messages.error(request, "We were unable to take a payment with that card!")
    else:
        payment_form = MakePaymentForm()
        order_form = OrderForm()

    return render(request, "checkout.html", {'order_form': order_form, 'payment_form': payment_form, 'publishable': settings.STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE})
```

Here are both the models that are referenced in the above view:

**Product**

```
class Product(models.Model):
    prod_creator_id = models.ForeignKey(User, null=False, default=1)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=38, default='')
    category = models.CharField(choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES, max_length=25, default='')
    description = models.TextField()
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images')
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**Customer**

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Here are both the forms that are referenced:

**OrderForm**

```
class OrderForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = (
            'full_name', 'phone_number', 'country', 'postcode',
            'town_or_city', 'street_address1', 'street_address2',
            'county'
        )
```

**MakePaymentForm**

```
class MakePaymentForm(forms.Form):

    MONTH_CHOICES = [(i, i) for i in range(1, 12)]
    YEAR_CHOICES = [(i, i) for i in range(2019, 2036)]

    credit_card_number = forms.CharField(label='Credit card number', required=False)
    cvv = forms.CharField(label='Security code (CVV)', required=False)
    expiry_month = forms.ChoiceField(label='Month', choices=MONTH_CHOICES, required=False)
    expiry_year = forms.ChoiceField(label='Year', choices=YEAR_CHOICES, required=False)
    stripe_id = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput)
```

Also, here is the JS that is being used for Stripe payments:

```
$(function() {
    $("#payment-form").submit(function() {
        var form = this;
        var card = {
            number: $("#id_credit_card_number").val(),
            expMonth: $("#id_expiry_month").val(),
            expYear: $("#id_expiry_year").val(),
            cvc: $("#id_cvv").val()
        };

    Stripe.createToken(card, function(status, response) {
        if (status === 200) {
            $("#credit-card-errors").hide();
            $("#id_stripe_id").val(response.id);

            //Prevent the credit card details from being submitted to our server
            $("#id_credit_card_number").removeAttr('name');
            $("#id_cvv").removeAttr('name');
            $("#id_expiry_month").removeAttr('name');
            $("#id_expiry_year").removeAttr('name');

            form.submit();

        } else {
            $("#stripe-error-message").text(response.error.message);
            $("#credit-card-errors").show();
            $("#validate_card_btn").attr("disabled", false);
        }
    });
    return false;
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance for any feedback!

Comment: You have not shared `OrderForm` & `MakePaymentForm` code.

Comment: @JBenno97 you must have ```stripe_id``` in your forms and this field is ```required``` as a result when you submit them form you get this error since you didn't fill this field. Add ```forms``` as well, this can help a lot.

Comment: Apologies @Kuldeep, completely forgot to add the forms. They're on there now.

Comment: Couldn't add both usernames at the same time @iliya

Comment: @JBenno97  here in your form ```MakePaymentForm``` you've got ```stripe_id``` and it is required you must fill this field in your template. Since you are adding this by ```HiddenInput``` you can not see it in your template. You must provide it by setting a valid id in your ```view``` then ```save``` the forms

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up @iliya! I'm still a little confused as to where I precisely need to add a valid id in my view?

Comment: @JBenno97, Actually you have `stripe_id` as hidden & required field as shown in `MakePaymentForm`. So you need to populate this field by some javascript code before submitting the form.

Comment: @Kuldeep I actually had some Stripe JavaScript stored on my site, so I've just added that above if you want to take a look :)

Answer (score 0):

Does your HTML markup end up actually *having* a `id_stripe_id` field that'd get submitted? That is, how are you rendering your form? If you're rendering each field manually, [you'll also need to loop over hidden fields](
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/#looping-over-hidden-and-visible-fields):

```
{% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
{{ hidden }}
{% endfor %}
```